# oracle Timestamp not supported in java.sql scala

Tags: sql, oracle, scala, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to query a oracle db table using spark sql. There is a `column(RESERVATION.START_DATE)` with datatype `timestamp` and when I run the query I get the error `unsupported type -101`. If I cast convert/cast the column to string/varchar or date type, I get `null` entries in my DataFrame.

I have tried using `to_char`, `to_date`, cast function to cast the timestamp value to string or date, if I run the query manually in the DBConsole I get correct results, but if I run it through a Scala program using `spark-sql` I get an unsupported type error or if I cast the column to string/date I get null values in DataFrame.

**Both the queries when run simply using oracle DBConsole are giving correct results with no error.
But if same queries are run using spark-sql in Scala i, get errors**

```
SELECT to_char(RESERVATION.START_DATE, 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS.FFFFFF TZH:TZM') as SDATE
  FROM RESERVATION  

SELECT RESERVATION.START_DATE,
  FROM RESERVATION
```

**Result for 1st query appears like(focus on first three values only. 3rd values is the START_DATE column)**

[null] ,

[null] ,
[null]

**Error result for second query is:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type -101
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getCatalystType(JdbcUtils.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.getSchema(JdbcUtils.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
```

Comment: We're going to need to see the actual code which is doing the SQL insert in order to help you.

Comment: Simplify the example removing all not relevant columns and make it reproducible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i did not perform the insert operations. I am working on a database someone else created(actually a lot of people contributed). I need to extract the columns. What i know is the datatype of START_DATE column is TIMESTAMP with TIMEZONE (DD-MM-RR HH12:MI:SSXFF AM TZR).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Sorry, i am running it on QA database so it's hard to make it reproducible but you can try if you have a oracle.What i dont understand is when i put a where(where START_DATE is not null) condition to check if START_DATE is null, then in the DBConsole the condition evaluates to true and i get results ,while when i run the query in  spark-sql the condition evaluates to false(START_DATE is evaluated as null) and i get empty DataFrame.